# Existe alguma maneira de rodar o C# pela linha de comando em modo interativo?

Tags: c#, linha-de-comando

Eu estou acostumado a usar PHP e Python, linguagens essas que permitem você rodar na linha de comando em modo interativo, sendo assim mais fácil de testar ou aprender alguma coisa nova, já que eu não precisarei compilar toda hora (como é no caso do C#).

Existe alguma maneira de usar o C# na linha de comando, em modo interativo?

Por exemplo, em Python eu posso fazer isso:

```
$ python
>>> 1 + 2
>>> # 3
```

A resposta pode ser para o `Windows`, mas se tiver alguma forma de fazer no `Linux`, ficaria grato com uma solução.

Eu uso o sistema operacional Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Existe há bastante tempo algumas opções, agora tem um [componente oficial](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Interactive-Window) funcionando junto ao Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 pra frente (mas não precisa dele para funcionar). [Mais informações no blog do Scott Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/InteractiveCodingWithCAndFREPLsScriptCSOrTheVisualStudioInteractiveWindow.aspx).

É para ele funcionar com o .NET Core no Linux, mas não tenho informações de como está o suporte (em geral tudo no .NET Core vai muito bem no Linux, até melhor), se precisa de algum esforço adicional ou está pronto para uso.

[Matéria na MSDN Magazine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2016/january/essential-net-csharp-scripting?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

Outras opções (algumas só *on-line*):

- [Mono REPL](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/tools+libraries/tools/repl/)
- [CSharpPad](http://csharppad.com/)
- [Extensão independente para o VS](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DinisCruz.VisualStudioCREPL&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397)
- [CShell](http://cshell.net/)

Algumas pessoas ainda gostam mais do [REPL do LINQPad](https://www.linqpad.net/CodeSnippetIDE.aspx).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Interessante é que no meu Ubuntu estava instalado um comando `csharp` e eu não sabia. Ele também serve +1

Comment: @WallaceMaxters aí não sei, só conheço o `csi` que é o REPL no Windows quando instala tudo.

Comment: Estou confuso, não sei se ele instalou como `mono-complete`, `dnx` ou `dotnet core` (aquele link que você me passou)

Comment: @WallaceMaxters Tem cara de ser do Mono.

Comment: Até agora eu não sabia o que era REPL, dava uma boa pergunta, kkkkkk

Answer (score 6):

Existe, no Visual Studio 2015 há um componente oficial para isso.

É só entrar em **`View > Other windows > C# interactive`** que um painel será aberto.

[Fonte](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Interactive-Window)